# Ruby giving Error while assigning

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I am new to ruby I was just trying this in "irb"

```
string = "www.google.com"

a,e=string.count "a", string.count "e"
```

It's giving an error

```
SyntaxError: (irb):50: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
a,e=string.count "a", string.count "e"
                                    ^
```

I am using ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close to your answer. A minor change in your code would work:

```
string = "www.google.com"
a, e = string.count("a"), string.count("e")
#=> [0, 1]
p a #=> 0
p e #=> 1
```

Comment: You don't need the `[]` if you put parens around the args to `string.count`.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I am sorry, I didn't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: +1 to @DaveNewton, if it's an example of parallel assignment, they draw attention away from it.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Ruby doesn't require parenthesis around parameters to methods, but they're a good idea, and I insist on them in our internal code because of these sort of problems. It's better to use them when you don't need them, than to need them, not use them, and write a bug into your code that is then hard to diagnose. Ruby isn't always so kind as to return an Exception; Sometimes it is happy to continue with weird results and no error.